# Codingbat:Warmup- last2 showing compile error on the online compiler even though it works perfectly in the interactive shell

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a Python and stack overflow newbie.

The following was the problem statement at http://codingbat.com/prob/p145834

> Given a string, return the count of the number of times that a
>   substring length 2 appears in the string and also as the last 2 chars
>   of the string, so "hixxxhi" yields 1 (we won't count the end
>   substring).
>
> Expected Outputs:
>   last2('hixxhi') → 1 
>   last2('xaxxaxaxx') → 1 
>   last2('axxxaaxx') → 2

The following is my code:

```
def last2(str):
  flag=0
  count=0
  ss=str[-2]+str[-1]
  for i in range(0,len(str)-1,1):
      flag=1
      for j in range(0,2,1):
          if ss[j]!=str[i+j]:
              flag=0
              break
      if(flag==1):
          count=count+1
  return count-1
```

**Explaining the code:**
The code is based on the standard algorithm for searching a sub-string in a string. Here ss stands for sub-string which takes the last two characters of the string str. The sub-string is searched for in the string and count stores the number of repetitions.  The value count-1 is returned since we don't want the last two characters to be counted as a repetition in accordance with the problem statement.

This is working perfectly on the offline interactive shell (using python 3.5).

[Screenshot enclosed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79677.png)

But the online compiler/interpreter shows the following error message for the same code:

> Compile problems:
>
> Error:string index out of range

(Screenshot not enclosed because of less than 10 reputation as I am a newbie)

What is the reason for the error?

Comment: The tag `compiler-errors` is misleading as this is clearly a runtime error.

Comment: I will remove that tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens when you try
`last2("")` in the interpreter?

I think that is where your problem lies.

However, the question doesn't say about what to do about strings of length < 2, so it's a bit funny for it to expect you to deal with it.

I made a nice quick solution that does work, but I'll let you find it your own solution, unless you want more help.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You are right: I had missed the test case last2(''). I simply had to add an if condition to take len(str)<2 into account.

Comment: Your solution seems to be quite ”chatty”. :-)
def last2(string):
    s = string[-2:];
    return sum(string[i:i + 2] == s for i in range(len(string))) - bool(s)

Comment: That works! Finally understood it. Thanks for this. Are there any resources you would recommend for learning Python further? I am currently using this: https://automatetheboringstuff.com/

Comment: I've never used it, but that looks like a decent resource. I used codeacademy back in the day but I'm not confident it's the best resource. Downey's Think Python should be decent. Imho the key thing is to keep trying to improve and to write good, clean code. You'll improve over time. You'll come across gems that just work for you. For instance, this revolutionised my code: http://nedbatchelder.com/text/iter.html. Learn comprehensions like BlackJack used. Remember the Zen of Python: in your python consol, type `import this`. If you do all of these things there is no doubt that you'll improve.